# Get around cy.downloadFile throwing a self signed certificate error

Tags: cypress

I've been using cypress-downloadfile all day to download a file from the testing site, now all of a sudden the test is failing right on the test with the following error.

> request to https://www.site.ca/ExportCase.ashx?id=a3607228-892a-6afc-a007-ff0000973b9b failed, reason: self signed certificate

The plugin seems to be failing here

```js
return cy.task('downloadFile', {
```

Gives me a Learn More Link over to https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task

I'm on 12.4.0... Tried on 12.3.0, same deal

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by disabling the check in `cypress.config.ts`

`setupNodeEvents`

add the line

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'; // otherwise, remotes with self-signed certificates are rejected.
```